# How to get unique latest updated database?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I was trying to retrieve where i want to get data based on unique id and But the latest one.

ie,

```
id  customer_name  uniqueId
1    x             1123
2    y             1123
3    z             1124
4    m             1125
5    n             1125
```

expected output after query:

```
id customer_name uniqueId
1    y            1123
2    z            1124
3    n            1125
```

I used the following statements but couldn't get the expected answer:

```
 $customers = DB::table('customers')
              ->select('uniqueId','customer_name','id','created_at')
              ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
              ->groupBy('uniqueId')                
              ->get();
```

Can anyone suggest me the right answer?

Comment: What you get with this query?

Comment: I got the old one not the latest value

Comment: First try to orderBy then use groupBy and tell me what happen.

Comment: Your output makes no sense and also I don't see the `created_at` column anywhere in your sample data.  Please make your question reproducible.

Comment: I saw same output @ChoncholMahmud

Comment: If you can't give answer ..that's Ok.
But giving down vote due to your incapability isn't accepted. to all who are giving down votes.
I found the question necessary as i didn't find any expected answer till yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problems. It would be some complex query. But it solved your problems. It is raw query. I run raw query by laravel query builder. If you get more simple query, then let us know.

```
$sql = "
SELECT p.`id`,p.`customer_name`,p.`uniqueId`
FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(created_at) AS created_at
  FROM `customers` 
  GROUP BY `uniqueId`
) t
LEFT JOIN `customers` p ON t.created_at = p.`created_at`
"
$customers = DB::select($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like:

```
SELECT [id],[customer_name],[uniqueId] 
FROM [Table name]
WHERE [id]= 2 OR ID = 3 OR ID = 5
```

Or with the IN clause

```
where id in (id1,id2.........long list)
```

If you really want to change the id to (1,2,3) you can always export this data somewhere else like new table i.e. and do the update function.

i.e.

```
UPDATE Your Table Here
SET id = 1
WHERE [unique_id]=1123
```

etc.

Cheers,
Kacper